# Splitting strings with std::getline

Tags: c++, stl

I copy the code from this answer [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

void split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

---

### I also add the code to check if `item.empty()`

Test code --

```
#include <xxx>

using namespace std;
string str = "0x0   0";
vector<string> result = split (str, ' ');
```

The result should be --

```
["0x0",   "0"]
```

But It doesn't split the string, and the result is --

```
["0x0   0"]
```

However, It works fine when --

```
str = "a    b  c d   ";
```

Is there something that I miss when using `std::getline()` ?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2acde687043340b1).  Do note that every space gets treated as a empty string when you have multiple empty spaces in a row.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's weird that if I run your code, everything works fine. But once I put those two functions into a header called `helper.h` and `helper.cpp`, it will have the same issue.